# Color shapes in 2d array with Processing

Tags: arrays, colors, 2d, processing, shapes

I'm new at programming, so sorry for the stupid question. I searched this site and others and found my question, but I couldn't apply their solutions, because their programming was different.

I have 10x10 grid and I need to color one of the rows or the columns. I've tried adding if statements in "for" but couldn't define row and col there. I'm very confused and I'd be glad if you could help me, thanks!

[This is the task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51kkS.png)

```
void setup()
{
  size(400,400);
  noStroke();
  fill(180,50, 50, 100);
}

void draw()
{
  background(255);

  for (int row=0; row<10; row = row+1)
  {
    for (int col=0; col<10; col = col+1)
    {
      if(col==4)
      {fill(255,0,0);
       ellipse(20+col*40,20+row*40,30,30);}
      else{
      ellipse(20 + col*40, 20 + row*40,30,30);}
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `I've tried adding if statements in "for" but couldn't define row and col there.` Please post exactly what you've tried, along with exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: Don't edit the comment. Edit your original post to include the code.

Comment: @KevinWorkman done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Kevin Workman pointed out, you have set the `fill` but forgot to change it back. Since you pointed out that you are a beginner, think of drawing stuff as "stateful", which means that unless and until the state is changed again, it will be maintained as set. This goes for properties like strokes, fills, all the colours, current co-ordinates, etc,..

When you go into a more advanced level, you might need to save and restore states, which can be done using matrix transformations. For a very brief primer on states refer to this [Jenkov tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/state.html).

As for your code, adding `fill(180,50,50)` to the else block should fix your problem.

```
...
  if(col==4){
    fill(255,0,0); //The different color for 4th column
    ellipse(20+col*40,20+row*40,30,30);
  } else{
    fill(180,50,50);  //The default color
    ellipse(20+col*40, 20+row*40,30,30);
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) so you understand exactly what your program is doing.

You have a nested `for` loop that loops over every circle in the grid. The first time you see `col==4`, you set the fill value to red. But then you never change the fill value back to its original color!

You probably want to set the fill value for **every** circle in the grid.